# Check if while loop is in first iteration in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

How Can i check if it's the first iteration in my `while loop` in C#?

```
while (myCondition)
{
   if(first iteration)
     {
       //Do Somthin
     }

   //The rest of the codes
}
```

Comment: with a variable in the outer scope, which is set after the first iteration to true/false ...

Comment: You could also do whatever you need to do on first iteration _before_ the `while`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
bool firstIteration = true;
while (myCondition)
{
   if(firstIteration )
     {
       //Do Somthin
       firstIteration = false;
     }

   //The rest of the codes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could move the do something out of the loop. Only guaranteed to do the exact same if the "Do Somthin" does not change `myCondition`. And `myCondition` test is pure, i.e. no side effects.

```
if (myCondition)
{
  //Do Somthin
}
while (myCondition)
{
   //The rest of the codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a counter:

```
int index = 0;
while(myCondition)
{
   if(index == 0) {
      // Do something
   }
   index++;
}
```

Comment: Although, if i need a counter for a loop i use a `for`-loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I understand your suggestion but for readability I am (personally) using this rule: Use a `for`-loop if your iteration can become 'out of range'. so your check of the `for`-loop checks whether you are not out of range. Use a `while`-loop if your condition is not that obvious referring to a range.

Comment: This assumes the loop actually iterates over something. What if `myCondition` is true while `index` overflows? Then you have the `// Do something` block executed twice.

Comment: This can be handy if you have an Enumerable and you only want to execute it once. You couldn't use an indexer with a for loop in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a bool outside the loop

```
 bool isFirst = true;
 while (myCondition)
 {
    if(isFirst)
      {
         isFirst = false;
        //Do Somthin
      }
    //The rest of the codes
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var first=true;
while (myCondition)
{
   if(first)
     {
       //Do Somthin
     }

   //The rest of the codes
first=false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a boolean variable:

```
bool firstTime = true;

while (myCondition)
{
   if(firstTime)
     {
         //Do Somthin
         firstTime = false;
     }

   //The rest of the codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by workarounds, like:

```
boolean first = true;

    while (condition) 
    {
        if (first) {
            //your stuff
            first = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
bool firstIteration = true;
while (myCondition)
{
   if(firstIteration)
     {
       //Do Something
       firstIteration = false;
     }

   //The rest of the codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using  counter variable for this, or a for loop.

E.G.

```
int i = 0;
while (myCondition)
{
   if(i == 0)
     {
       //Do Something
     }
i++;
   //The rest of the codes
}
```

Comment: why do you recommend a counter over a `bool`-variable?

Comment: @Andreas a counter would let you have multiple cases I suppose

Comment: I would use a `for`-loop if i need a counter.

Comment: @GrawCube ;) *I* know, but I wanted the author to include this information to the answer. Recommending without reasoning is a bit cumbersome ...

Comment: I did recommend using a for loop

Answer (score -1):

Still learning, but this way came to me, have not used this before myself but I plan to test and possibly implement in my project:

```
int invCheck = 1;

if (invCheck > 0)
    {
        PathMainSouth(); //Link to somewhere
    }
    else
    {
        ContinueOtherPath(); //Link to a different path
    }

    static void PathMainSouth()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }

    static void ContinueOtherPath()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Please test the solution you have shared also give a complete solution.